# Global Javascript link handler

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dom-events, event-delegation

Here's what I have:

- A web application that runs in a single HTML page (call it `myapp.req`), with content coming and going via AJAX
- The application can be entered externally with a link such as `myapp.req?id=123`, and the application opens a tab with the item at id 123
- The content on the page is mostly user's content, and many times has inner-application links to `myapp.req?id=123`
- The problem is that clicking a link to `myapp.req?id=123` reloads the browser, and removes any content or state that the user had loaded

What I want is to be able to catch link clicks whose destination is `myapp.req?id=123`, and instead of reloading the page, just open the tab for item 123, leaving anything else currently loaded alone.  If the link is for an external website, though, obviously just let the browser leave.

So my question really: Can I have a global link handler that checks if I want to handle the link click, and if so, run some Javascript and don't leave?

I understand I could find all `<a>`s and add listeners, but my hope is that the solution would only require setting up the listener once, and not adding link handlers every time new content is loaded on the page.  Since content can be loaded many different ways, it would be cumbersome to add code to all those places.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Add a clickhandler on the body. So you catch all clicks. Then you have to check if the target of the event or one of its parent is a link with your specific href. In this case stop the event and open the tab.

Answer (score 2):

[**jQuery's live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is what you need:

```
$('a').live("click", function () {
    var myID = $(this).attr('href').match(/id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\&?/)[1];
    if (myID) {
        //run code here
        alert(myID);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any link will now have this click handler whether it's been added after this is called or not.

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery isn't an optionin my application right now, so I went with another answer as the solution.  Thanks for this info though!

Answer (score 0):

**updated** to use `.live` instead of `.click`

If you use jQuery, you can add a "live" click event handler to every `a href` at once:

```
<body>
    <a href="app.req?id=123&test=432">click here</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://whatever.com">whatever</a>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('a').live('click',function() {
    var myID = $(this).attr('href').match(/id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\&?/)[1];
    if (myID) {
        //run code here
        alert(myID);
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

This should extract the id from the href's query string and let you do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I was trying to avoid.  The code you provided would only add the listener for every link that is currently on the page, but the content of the page changes all the time, and new links can be rendered often.  Thus I would need to run your code every time I render new content.  Instead, I'm hoping for a global listener that simply always gets to run when any link is clicked, before the browser leaves the page.

Comment: instead of a click use live.. it should take care of any new elements coming into the page..